# Creating a Team Drive through Drive API from an organization-external account?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Hello all here's my situation, in as simple of terms as possible.

- I have the Google Drive API enabled for a Google Cloud Platform project.
- A code script belonging to that GCP project is shared with accounts that are external to my G Suite organization.
- This script creates Team Drive folders automatically.
- When running this script from the external account, a Team Drive is created in the Google Drive to which the script belongs, not in the Google Drive that belongs to the external user.
- I would like the Team Drive to be created in the Google Drive that belongs to the external user who is running the script.

I understand that, without using the Advanced Services I could reference the REST API directly, and have the Team Drive created in the proper Google Drive just by differentiating between credentials that are defined uniquely for both Google Drives, but how is this accomplished with this wrapper library?

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-teamdrives), it appears that Team drives can only be created for organization accounts not individual accounts.

Comment: Ah okay, does this account for the difference of, say, when using a non-advanced google service, a verification step is asked of Google to allow permissions of the script to operate on behalf of the individual account? In which case, how would I interface with the activation of the google drive API on one google cloud platform project to work for any number of uses by many different accounts external to the organization, and have team drives be created in their organizations? @DimuDesigns